# Unexpected atoms while working with XYZ files in rdkit

Tags: python, rdkit

I am processing some XYZ files using the `rdkit` library in python. I came across some strange/unexpected behaviour.

Consider a sample XYZ file of methanol with coordinates in Angstroms:

```
6
Methanol
  H      1.2001      0.0363      0.8431
  H      0.9877      0.8943     -0.7114
  H      1.0155     -0.8918     -0.6742
  C      0.7031      0.0083     -0.1305
  O     -0.6582     -0.0067      0.1730
  H     -1.1326     -0.0311     -0.6482
```

I am using the following code to visualise this compound. I am running the below code on Google Colab.

```
!pip install rdkit
from rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles import  MolFromXYZFile

coord_filepath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/input_files/methanol.xyz'
mol = MolFromXYZFile(coord_filepath)
display(mol)
```

The output from the display looks like this:

[image]

I am a bit puzzled about the extra Hydrogens in the image.
I tried to double check the atoms in the rdkit `mol`

```
for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
  print(atom.GetSymbol())
```

It displays as expected:

```
H
H
H
C
O
H
```

With coordinates in nanometers, the behaviour persists, with a bit better spacing between the various atoms/molecules.

[image]

So is this behaviour a bug or am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: I have never heard of the MolFromXYZFile function in RDKit before, if I remember correctly, rdkit wasn't able to read xyz files. So this is probably a newly implemented feature in rdkit, and maybe buggy because of that.

Comment: https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.html#rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MolFromXYZFile 

You can find the documentation for the function here.

Comment: It looks RDKit thinks it read in isolated atoms and "auto-hydrogenated" them into one water, one methane and four hydrogen molecules. Maybe it was expecting nm (your coordinates look like angstroms) and thus could not auto-detect bonds between the atomic positions.

Comment: @ShernRenTee The behaviour persists even when I use nanometers. I have updated the question with details. Please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/rdkit/UGM_2022/blob/main/Notebooks/Landrum_WhatsNew.ipynb) is a demo how to work with `MolFromXYZ`.

You can choose `rdDetermineBonds.DetermineConnectivity` for bonds or `rdDetermineBonds.DetermineBonds`for bonds and bond orders.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdDetermineBonds

xyz = '''6
Methanol
  H      1.2001      0.0363      0.8431
  H      0.9877      0.8943     -0.7114
  H      1.0155     -0.8918     -0.6742
  C      0.7031      0.0083     -0.1305
  O     -0.6582     -0.0067      0.1730
  H     -1.1326     -0.0311     -0.6482'''

mol = Chem.MolFromXYZBlock(xyz)

conn_mol = Chem.Mol(mol)
rdDetermineBonds.DetermineConnectivity(conn_mol)
conn_mol
```

[image: mol]